# yii2 get getter's value in active query request (using asArray())

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have the next code:

```
    $fixed_events = EventMain::find()
        ->select(["id", "title", "files"])
        //->joinWith(['files'])
        //->with(['files'])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

How can i get array with "files" value, taking into account, that the "files" is modle's getter like

```
public function getFiles()
{
    return (json_decode($this->all_files, true)) ?: [];
}
```

Comment: If you remove `asArray()` from the query and loop over the result like `foreach($fixed_events  as $event) {  print_r($event->files); }` This way you can access the `files array` for each model object. Would that sufice in your scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `files` is not a relation with `EventMain` table, I guess the easiest approach would be handle the data and convert with [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray()-detail) after coming from db:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


$models = EventMain::find()->select(['id', 'title'])->all();

$array = ArrayHelper::toArray($models, [
    'app\models\EventMain' => ['id', 'title','files']
]);

var_dump($array);
?>
```